# How could I delete certain columns then write wanted columns into csv python

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file and I would like to remove certain columns I don't need. 
For example,

```
   ID,Name,Nickname,Income,Car,  ..............
    1,A,test,12k,Benz, ..............
    2,B,test1,23k,Audi, ..............
    3,C,test2,20k,BMW,  ..............
```

However, I do not need their Nickname and Car brand *etc* information. 
Thus I have another .csv file to list the columns' information I do not need.

```
Remove_list,
Nickname,
Car,
.
.
.
.
.
```

Finally I'd like to get a new .csv output file such as below.

```
ID,Name,Income, ......
1,A,12k,   ......
2,B,23k,   .......
3,C,20k,   ........
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I only know how to work it out by row direction rather than column.

And also I found someone has done this by c# however I only work on python.
(see c# example, [How do I delete certain column from .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991609/how-do-i-delete-certain-column-from-csv-file) )

Much appreciated for help,

Comment: Your files don't look like csv files

Comment: Oh sorry I did not add comma between each data. Thanks for reminder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the csv files `orig.csv`:

```
ID,Name,Nickname,Income,Car
1,A,test,12k,Benz
2,B,test1,23k,Audi
3,C,test2,20k,BMW
```

and `remove_list.csv`:

```
Nickname
Car
```

we can do something like this to filter:

```
def remove_cols():
    remove_list = []

    with open('remove_list.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            remove_list.append(line.strip())

    colIndexesToKeep = []

    with open('orig.csv') as origFile:
        with open('filtered.csv', 'w') as filteredFile:
            for line in origFile:
                if not colIndexesToKeep:
                    for ix, name in enumerate(line.split(',')):
                        if name.strip() not in remove_list:
                            colIndexesToKeep.append(ix)

                filteredLine = [val.strip() for ix, val in 
                  enumerate(line.split(',')) if ix in colIndexesToKeep]
                filteredFile.write(','.join(filteredLine))     
                filteredFile.write('\n')
```

which gives the output `filtered.csv`:

```
ID,Name,Income
1,A,12k
2,B,23k
3,C,20k
```

Comment: sorted, much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to do so whereas my reputation is not enough therefore I cannot up-vote your guys answer. I will supply vote again once I get sufficient reputation! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the del statement to delete a value in a list.
Assuming you have the csv data in the "csv_table" variable, and the list of headers to delete in the "columns" variable, you can do something like this:

```
columns_indexes = sorted([index for index,column in enumerate(csv_table[0]) 
if column in columns],reverse=True)
for line in csv_table:
    for index in columns_indexes:
        del line[index]
```

The csv_table variable will now reflect the list you wanted. You can easily read for a csv file using the csv module.

Comment: sorted, much appreciated.