# Extract text from specific columns in c#?

Tags: c#, csv

I have been working on extracting text from a csv file and store the data in a string. But now, I would like to extract text from some of the specific columns  and store the data in a string.I would like the `wordDocContents` variable to contain the specific columns and the data in those specific columns  which is `bank_account`, `bank_name`, `customer_name`. Currently, my `wordDocContents` has the entire data from my csv file. Is there a way to filter out the specific columns and the data in those columns and store it in the variable `wordDocContents`. Thanks

Here is what I tried so far -

```
public void button1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    button1.Text = "You clicked me";

    var textExtractor = new TextExtractor();

    var wordDocContents = textExtractor.Extract("t.csv");
    Console.WriteLine(wordDocContents);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The contents of wordDocContents:-

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER,CUSTOMER_NAMES,VALUE_DATE,BOOKING_DATE,TRANSACTION,ACCOUNT_TYPE,BALANCE_TYPE,REFERENCE,MONEY.OUT,MONEY.IN,RUNNING.BALANCE,BRANCH,EMAIL,ACTUAL.BALANCE,AVAILABLE.BALANCE
1000000001,TEST,,2847899,KES,Account,,,10/10/2016,9/11/2016,15181800,UPPER HILL BRANCH,another@yahoo.com,5403.75,5403.75,
1000000001,,9/11/2016,9/11/2016,Opening Balance,,,,,,4643.22,,,,,
1000000001,,12/10/2016,12/10/2016,Mobile Mpesa Transfer,,,,1533,,3110.22,,,,,
1000000001,,17-10-2016,17-10-2016,ATM Withdrawal,,,6.29006E+11,1000,,2110.22,,,,,
1000000001,,17-10-2016,17-10-2016,ATM Withdrawal,,,6.29118E+11,2000,,110.22,,,,,
1000000001,,17-10-2016,17-10-2016,Mobile Mpesa Transfer,,,,2083,,-1972.78,,,,,
1000000001,,17-10-2016,17-10-2016,Transfer from Mpesa,,,,0,4000,2027.22,,,,,
1000000001,,18-10-2016,18-10-2016,Mobile Mpesa Transfer,,,,333,,1694.22,,,,,
```

Comment: you can loop through it and select only perticular columns

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande:- Can you kindly provide a small rough code or something that can explain the process?

Comment: can you put what you get in `wordDocContents`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande:- I have added the contents in wordDocContents.

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991609/how-do-i-delete-certain-column-from-csv-file` this will give you some idea..

Comment: Does the TextExtractor class offer you any options, or does it only have the Extract() method?

Comment: @Nick:- The TextExtractor class doesnt have the option to select specific columns.

Comment: @Jessica - where is the TextExtractor from and what other functions does it have?

Comment: @Nick:- Its TikaonDotNet textextractor

Comment: @Jessica - any reason you're using that tool? There's a CSV parser in  .NET Framework now, the TextFieldParser class. Did you check out some of the alternatives on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-with-header

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge on how csv files are constructed. (Maybe post the first 2 lines of your output?)

```
string[] lines = wordDocContents.Split("\n");
string[] columns = lines[0].Split(",");
string[][] data = new string[lines.Length][columns.Length];
```

Now let's say customer_name is under columns[2], you can try to:

```
List<string> customerNames = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++) {
customerNames.Add(data[i][2]);
}
```

Edit just saw the output, this code might need some adjusting for your particular case. I am not 100% sure if string.Split(",") works for multiple commas in a row, but it's worth a shot. Just change the [2] to whichever column you need.

It should be going from [0],[1],[2] etc.